# Sqoop import - importing table into HBASE with overwrite

Tags: hbase, sqoop

I want to import a oracle table into HBASE, and this is always full table replace (like hive overwrite option in sqoop), is there a way we can achieve this behavior with out going for "disbale 'table', drop 'table' before every sqoop import for this table.

Regards,
GHK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the comparison with Hive's "INSERT OVERWRITE" is not entirely accurate. Sqoop will get all data from relational database and import them into HBase, setting new version for values that are already there. Existing keys that happen not to be present in the source relational database are not touched by Sqoop on HBase side and therefore the table itself is not "overwritten" in the Hive sense.

Comment: Yes, we are have a plan of getting the updated/latest records based on last updated columns from oracle, but I just want to know if we would like to replace a table when we do not have a last updated column/ index on that column, is there any alternate way to do full table replace in Hbase, other than the way I described above.

Comment: I'm afraid that such functionality is not there at the moment. However don't hesitate and open a JIRA on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP

Comment: Defect for the same is raised : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1214.

Comment: Thank you for filling the JIRA!